# array_diff() with "one-for-one" element removal when there are duplicate array values

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, array-difference

I have two arrays containing repeating values:

```
$test1 = [
    "blah1",
    "blah1",
    "blah1",
    "blah1",
    "blah2"
];

$test2 = [
    "blah1",
    "blah1",
    "blah1",
    "blah2"
];
```

I am trying to get array difference:

```
$result = array_diff($test1,$test2);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

I need it to return array with single value `blah1`, yet it returns empty array instead.

I suspect it has something to do with fact there are duplicate values in both arrays, but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Your solution is good, but it will fails if you have `$array1 = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]` and `$array2 = [ 'd' ]`. The output should be the same as `$array1`, but will be `[ 'b', 'c' ]` because the `array_search()` will returns `false` when looking for `d`, and the `unset()` will drop the first key of `$array1` because `false == 0`. An `if` should helps on it ([gist](https://gist.github.com/rentalhost/e37628db9b3dc8e737c6b9153d617200), [run](https://3v4l.org/96frT)).

Comment: @Acidon I think you should add your own solution as an answer, cause I haven't found a better way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

`array_diff` compares the first `array` to the other `array`(s) passed as parameter(s) and `return`s an `array`, containing all the elements present in the first `array` that are not present in any other `array`s. Since `$test1` and `$test2` both contain `"blah1"` and `"blah2"`, and no other values, actually, the expected behavior of `array_diff` is the one that you have experienced, that is, to `return` an empty `array`, since, there is no element in `$test1` which is not present in `$test2`.

[Further read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php). Also, read [some theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29) to understand what you are working with.

Comment: I understand now, but what should I use instead to get the desired effect?

Comment: I guess I can loop over test1 and remove each matching value in both arrays, but was looking for more elegant solution

Comment: @Acidon, what should be the result if you have 5 pieces of "blah1" in the first array without "blah2" and the second array is left unchanged?

Comment: it should be "blah1","blah1" . The function in EDIT gets the result.

Comment: @Acidon, I see. Now I understand the problem you were asking about :)

Answer (score 2):

Spotted a problem with Acidon's own solution. The problem comes from the fact that `unset($array[false])` will actually unset `$array[0]`, so there needs to be an explicit check for `false` (as David Rodrigues pointed out as well.)

```
function subtract_array($array1,$array2){
    foreach ($array2 as $item) {
        $key = array_search($item, $array1);
        if ( $key !== false ) {
            unset($array1[$key]);
        }
    }
    return array_values($array1);
}
```

**Some examples**

```
subtract_array([1,1,1,2,3],[1,2]);            // [1,1,3]
subtract_array([1,2,3],[4,5,6]);              // [1,2,3]
subtract_array([1,2,1],[1,1,2]);              // []
subtract_array([1,2,3],[]);                   // [1,2,3]
subtract_array([],[1,1]);                     // []
subtract_array(['hi','bye'], ['bye', 'bye']); // ['hi']
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the scope of your task, it may be necessary to only remove elements from the first array which are "one-for-one" represented in the second array. In other cases, it may be appropriate to cross-check the differences in a "one-for-one" manner for both arrays and combine the remaining elements.

Consider this altered sample data set:

```
$test1 = [
    "blah1",
    "blah1",
    "blah2",
    "blah4",
    "blah5"
];

$test2 = [
    "blah1", // under-represented
    "blah2", // equally found
    "blah3", // not found
    "blah4", // over-represented
    "blah4", //       "
];
```

Below are four different functions (with indicative names) to offer varied utility.

Codes: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GGG8t))

- unilateral difference (iterated array searches):

  ```
  function removeBValuesFromA(array $a, array $b): array
  {
      foreach ($b as $bVal) {
          $k = array_search($bVal, $a);
          if ($k !== false) {
              unset($a[$k]);
          }
      }
      return array_values($a);
  }
  ```
- bilateral difference (iterated array searches):

  ```
  function bidirectionalDiff(array $a, array $b): array
  {
      foreach ($b as $bKey => $bVal) {
          $aKey = array_search($bVal, $a);
          if ($aKey !== false) {
              unset($a[$aKey], $b[$bKey]);
          }
      }
      return array_merge($a, $b);
  }
  ```
- unilateral difference (condense-compare-expand):

  ```
  function removeBValuesFromAViaCounts(array $a, array $b): array
  {
      $toRemove = array_count_values($b);

      $result = [];
      foreach (array_count_values($a) as $k => $count) {
          array_push(
              $result,
              ...array_fill(
                  0,
                  max(0, $count - ($toRemove[$k] ?? 0)),
                  $k
              )
          );
      }
      return $result;
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  function removeBValuesFromAViaCounts(array $a, array $b): array
  {
      $toRemove = array_count_values($b);

      $result = [];
      foreach (array_count_values($a) as $k => $count) {
          for ($i = 0; $i < $count - ($toRemove[$k] ?? 0); ++$i) {
              $result[] = $k;
          }
      }
      return $result;
  }
  ```
- bilateral difference (condense-compare-expand):

  ```
  function bidirectionalDiffViaCounts(array $a, array $b): array
  {
      $bCounts = array_count_values($b);

      $result = [];
      foreach (array_count_values($a) as $k => $count) {
          array_push(
              $result,
              ...array_fill(
                  0,
                  abs($count - ($bCounts[$k] ?? 0)),
                  $k
              )
          );
          unset($bCounts[$k]);
      }
      foreach ($bCounts as $k => $count) {
          array_push(
              $result,
              ...array_fill(0, $count, $k)
          );
      }
      return $result;
  }
  ```

Execution:

```
var_export([
    'removeBValuesFromA' => removeBValuesFromA($test1, $test2),
    'bidirectionalDiff' => bidirectionalDiff($test1, $test2),
    'removeBValuesFromAViaCounts' => removeBValuesFromAViaCounts($test1, $test2),
    'bidirectionalDiffViaCounts' => bidirectionalDiffViaCounts($test1, $test2),
]);
```

Outputs:

```
array (
  'removeBValuesFromA' => 
  array (
    0 => 'blah1',
    1 => 'blah5',
  ),
  'bidirectionalDiff' => 
  array (
    0 => 'blah1',
    1 => 'blah5',
    2 => 'blah3',
    3 => 'blah4',
  ),
  'removeBValuesFromAViaCounts' => 
  array (
    0 => 'blah1',
    1 => 'blah5',
  ),
  'bidirectionalDiffViaCounts' => 
  array (
    0 => 'blah1',
    1 => 'blah4',
    2 => 'blah5',
    3 => 'blah3',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal, you can use custom function:

```
 function array_diff_countable($array1, $array2) {
    $diff = [];

    $array1Counts = array_count_values($array1);
    $array2Counts = array_count_values($array2);

    foreach ($array1Counts as $key => $count) {
        $diffCount = $count - ($array2Counts[$key] ?? 0);
        if ($diffCount > 0) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $diffCount; $i++) {
                $diff[] = $key;
            }
        }
    }

    return $diff;
}
```

Comment: "use this custom function" is not an overly generous explanation to future readers.  Please [edit] your answer to explain how your script works and maybe why you would compel them to use your answer over other competing answers.  This answer certainly resembles the approach that I've demonstrated in two snippets in my answer; perhaps explain the advantage of your script over my earlier posted scripts.

Comment: To be clear, this answer is performing a "unilateral difference" https://3v4l.org/lgfYr (which doesn't not make it incorrect for the asked question).  It may be important for future readers to understand that it will not generate a result with the extra elements from the second array.  As a matter of editing, this answer can safely remove `if ($diffCount > 0) {` because that logic is enforced by the `for` loop itself.